# How do I reach this ledge under the broken stairs in Richter Mode?

Tags: dead-cells

Near the top right of the map in [Richter Mode](https://gamerant.com/dead-cells-richter-mode-unlock-how-return-to-castlevania-dlc/), there is a small ledge underneath a broken staircase. By this ledge there is a hidden set of set of candles inside the wall. I've tried jumping to it using my high jump and dash, but I keep getting blocked by the upper part of the stairs.

How do I reach this ledge under the broken stairs in Richter Mode? Do you get anything for breaking the candle there?

[image: hidden ledge under staircase]